# coreutils timeout in a bash script not transparent for the application

Tags: python, linux, bash, terminal, timeout

I have an issue with executing application via /usr/bin/timeout in a bash script.
In this specific case this is a simple python fabric script (fabric version 1.14)
In order to install this version of fabric library run: pip install "fabric<2"
There is no reproduction with new fabric 2.x.

Shell script causing issue:

```
[root@testhost:~ ] $ cat testNOK.sh
#!/bin/bash
timeout 10 ./test.py
echo "RETCODE=$?"
[root@testhost:~ ] $ ./testNOK.sh
[localhost] run: echo Hello!
RETCODE=124
[root@testhost:~ ] $
```

Similar script (without timeout) working fine

```
[root@testhost:~ ] $ cat testOK.sh
#!/bin/bash
./test.py
echo "RETCODE=$?"
[root@testhost:~ ] $ ./testOK.sh
[localhost] run: echo Hello!
[localhost] out: Hello!
[localhost] out:

RETCODE=0
[root@testhost:~ ] $
```

Manual execution from bash commandline with timeout working fine:

```
[root@testhost:~ ] $ timeout 10 ./test.py && echo "RETCODE=$?"
[localhost] run: echo Hello!
[localhost] out: Hello!
[localhost] out:

RETCODE=0
[root@testhost:~ ] $
```

Python2.7 test.py script

```
[root@testhost:~ ] $ cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/python
from fabric.api import run, settings

with settings(host_string='localhost', user='root', password='XXXXX'):
    run('echo Hello!')
[root@testhost:~ ] $
```

I have observed the same behavior on different Linux distributions.

Now the question is why application executed via timeout within bash script behaves in a different way and what would be the best solution to this issue?

Comment: Can you run `env -i bash --norc` to get a clean shell and verify that your command still works fine with manual execution?

Comment: Yes, still working fine:
# env -i bash --norc
bash-4.4# timeout 10 ./test.py && echo "RETCODE=$?"
[localhost] run: echo Hello!
[localhost] out: Hello!
[localhost] out:

RETCODE=0
bash-4.4#

Comment: Great. Now can you run `echo 'timeout 10 ./test.py && echo "RETCODE=$?"' > myfile && env -i bash --norc myfile` to verify that this exact command fails in a script in the same kind of shell?

Comment: that one is failing as well as `env -i bash --norc -c 'timeout 10 ./test.py && echo "RETCODE=$?"'` which is failing too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke `timeout` with the  `--foreground` option:

```
timeout --foreground ./test.py
```

This is only required if the `timeout` command is not executed from an interactive shell (that is, if it's executed from a script file).

Quoting from the `timeout` info page:

```
‘--foreground’
     Don’t create a separate background program group, so that the
     managed COMMAND can use the foreground TTY normally.  This is
     needed to support timing out commands not started directly from an
     interactive shell, in two situations.
       1. COMMAND is interactive and needs to read from the terminal for
          example
       2. the user wants to support sending signals directly to COMMAND
          from the terminal (like Ctrl-C for example)
```

What's actually going on in this case is that fabric (or something invokes) is calling `tcsetattr` to turn terminal echo off. I don't know why, but I suppose it has something to do with the process used to (not) collect the user password. (I just saw it in an strace; I made no attempt to find the call.) Attempting to change tty configuration from a background process will cause the process to block until it regains control of the tty, and that's what's happening.

It doesn't happen when `timeout` is not used because `bash` doesn't create a background program group. I suppose that fabric 2 avoids the call to `tcsetattr`.

You could probably also avoid the issue by avoiding password-based SSH authentication but I didn't try that.

You can also avoid the problem by redirecting `stdin` to `/dev/null` (either in the `timeout` command or in the invocation of the shell script.) If you don't need to forward stdin to the remote command (and you probably don't), that might also be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth analysis. Adding --foreground option indeed helps (application runs normally). Redirecting stdin to /dev/null `timeout 10 python ./test.py 0>/dev/null` causes application to crash with python IOError exception. Replacing password authentication with key authentication did not help. What is still not quite clear to me in the light of your analysis is the fact that the issue is observed only if app is invoked with the timeout tool from the bash script and from the command line is still working fine even with the use of timeout tool.

Comment: oh, maybe when invoked from the commandline the foreground is just default and in the bash script there are different terminal settings. The foreground vs background and terminal settings is not exactly my world.

Comment: @fakej: the redirect goes the other way: `timeout 10 python ./test.py </dev/null`.

Comment: oh, my bad, thank you for pointing that. I admit that it works well too!

Answer (score -1):

You Can Use time out without using bash Just by using the time model in python

```
import time

time.sleep(5)
#change the 5 by the seconds that you need to set a timeout
```

Comment: I guess you meant signal.alarm(). time.sleep() will not terminate an application

Comment: use better sys.exit()

Comment: The purpose of coreutils timeout as well as signal.alarm() is to send signal to application after specific amount of time unless application terminates itself. time.sleep() and sys.exit() are not replacement for that! sys.exit() will terminate python script instantly without letting it run for specific amount of time.